# How can i find exact amount of words after a number

Tags: php, regex, string

i have a text and inside this text are numbers. For the last number I need the exact same amount of words after the number. 
Can i write a regex for this? i don't have any idea.

Example:

> Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries
>   Vokalia and Consonantia, there live 3 blind texts. Separated they live
>   in 4 Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large
>   language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and
>   supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic
>   country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.
>   5
>   far
>   countries
>   Vokalia
>   Consonantia
>   blind

The expected result is:

> far
>   countries
>   Vokalia
>   Consonantia
>   blind

Comment: please rephrase the question

Comment: i have rephrase the question. Is it now clear for you? My English is not so good. sry

Comment: @Slash84 You need to show what you have tried so far.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Comment: you can not do it with regex alone..bit of PHP hack is required

Comment: post my solution as answer

Comment: You should add your solution to your question not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for this problem

```
$text = 'Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live 3 blind texts. Separated they live in 4 Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.
5
far
countries
Vokalia
Consonantia
blind';

preg_match('/(\d+)(?!.*\d)(.+?)\Z/', $text, $words);
var_dump(end($words));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing it without a lookbehind but I couldn't.

Anyway, here is the regex

```
(?<=\d)([^\d]+)$
```

Comment: You can use `\K` token to reset all previously captured characters from being existed in the results: `\d\K([^\d]+)$`